# blank space gets automatically replaced by underscore

Tags: php, html, forms

I have the following php code in my input field:

```
<input type="submit" name='<?php echo $row["date"];?>' value="send">
```

a `var_dump($row["date"])` shows the data is a string like so:

```
string '2015-10-03 19:01:47' (length=19)
```

Why then, when I post this form, does the blank space get automatically replaced by an underscore and how can I avoid that?

`var_dump($_POST)`:

```
array (size=1)
'2015-10-03_19:01:47' => string 'send' (length=4)
```

Comment: This is your browser fixing your (invalid) code. An input field name cannot have arbitrary names. For example it cannot have a blank inside the name. Your browser tries to fix that for you.

Comment: What if the inputed `date` is `205-10-03 19:01:47         `? Maybe you should aware of that. And I think the value is the date not name right?

Answer (score 1):

*and how can I avoid that?*

You can use `str_replace` to get the desired behavior:

```
<?php
$send = '2015-10-03_19:01:47';
echo str_replace("_"," ",$send);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2015-10-03 19:01:47
```

[PHP Manual: str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: yes I was thinking of using the str_replace as a workaround as well. However, since I'm replacing a specific character (namely the underscore), which I didn't specifically put there in the first place, my concern is that under different circumstances a different browser might replace the inintial blank space with something else than "_" which would make the str_replace futile.

Comment: @user5355646 Ahh, _I'm replacing a specific character (namely the underscore), which I didn't specifically put there in the first place,_  well that is a valid question. I tested it on two different browsers and it worked. But who really knows it would end up on any other browser, using a `hidden` field would be better. `:-)`

Comment: thanks! But your suggestion to use hidden fields brings up a different problem, which is that I want to post the date for a selected (=submiitted) row, but if I use hidden fields which all have the same name 'date', then I don't get the selected value.

Answer (score 1):

As @arkascha has explained in his comment.

> *ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").*

So it is not possible to have space as a name. You asked how to avoid this one? Simple, just don't use the date as the name of the input. You can have hidden input field that hold the date value.

```
<input type="hidden" name='date' value='<?php echo $row["date"];?>'>
<input type="submit" name='submit' value="send">
```

Alternatively, you can use `<button>`

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row["date"]; ?>">Submit</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I didn't know that and strangely it actually works even if you use numbers only as a name (however, apparently not including blank spaces). Anyway, your suggestion to use hidden fields brings up a different problem, which is that I want to post the date for a selected (=submiitted) row, but if I use hidden fields which all have the same name 'date', then I don't get the selected value.